# Tree parsing in Prolog

Tags: tree, prolog

you can suggest the following: I have something like a warehouse and I gained a graph out of it. The vertices are (0-0), (0-1) and so on and the edges are weighted, for example: e(0-0,0-1,1).

From this graph (which has cycles) I gained with the Prim algorithm a minimal spanning tree. And now my question:

I want to go through the whole tree with backtracking, something like

```
tree_walker(Es, X) :-
   member(e(X,Y,_), Es),
   tree_walker(Es, Y).
```

How can I do this? My main problem is the representation of the tree (showing below), because other trees in examples, found at the internet, are represented an other way. So I can't catch the idea of solving this problem.

My representation of a sample minimal spanning tree with four vertices: (0-0), (0-1), (1-0) and (1-1)

```
[e(0-0,0-1,1),e(0-0,1-0,1),e(0-1,1-1,2)]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tree walker also needs a representation of the node it is currently visiting. An additional clause is used to report each node it is visiting as a solution:

```
tree_walker(_, Node, Node).
tree_walker(Es, From, To) :-
     member(e(From,Next,_), Es),
     tree_walker(Es, Next, To).
```

You post a query like:

```
?- tree_walker(Es, Start, Node).
```

and obtain visited nodes as a sequence of solutions that are reported by the toplevel.

+1 for avoiding side effects, and instead using the Prolog toplevel for reporting solutions.

Comment: first of all, thanks for your help!! I've understood your solution by adding the To-parameter and the additional clause. But now my question: How can I parse the whole tree??

Comment: Do you mean *walk* the whole tree? On backtracking, each node that *can* be visited *will* be visited. You can use `findall/3` to collect all solutions.

Answer (score 0):

prolog code to numberize a list ,which can include tree
     constants, and perform deep on the list.  E.g.
     [14,sdsd,a(b,27,c(16,[dfdf]))] would become 
       [14,0,a(0,27,c(16,[0]))].  it replaces leaf atoms by the number zero.